# Cannot play For Honor since Playstation Now subscription ended

Tags: psn, for-honor

I added For Honor to my library when it was free, and after my subscription ended I used my 'PlayStation Now' subscription to play it. However, since my 'PlayStation Now' subscription ended, I have been unable to play For Honor.
I made the PS4 system my main system and updated my game's licence, but neither worked.

Comment: Review your question, and edit it please, your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Have you renewed your subscription? It seems like the game was tied to your PS Now subscription so I'd imagine you'd have to either buy the game or renew the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

If I don't misunderstand, your problem is that once the 'PlayStation now' subscription is over, you can't play For Honor. Probably that is because, to play For Honor you need the subscription to 'PlayStation now'.

Answer (score 1):

you must mean ps plus but anyway games you get while having "plus" or "now" you don't keep any games unless you keep paying the monthly subscription. now if you don't pay for a month then start paying again you will get those games back.